# Change GNOME Activities Overview Highlight Color

Tags: gnome, themes, colors, accessibility, css

The GNOME activities overview allows you to select items, all the while using a gray background, and a dark gray highlight to indicate the item selected (see picture below `Utilities`). There is almost no contrast between gray and dark gray. How can I do one of the following to make it easier to visibly see what I've selected:

- Change the activities overview background color.
- Change the selected item highlight color.
- Put a bright blue line around the border of selected item.
- Any other ideas to let me know what selected item is currently selected.

[image: gnome activities overview image]